# How do I suppress output with fc when there are no differences

Tags: cmd.exe, difftool

I want to compare a bunch of files in a cmd.exe batch file using `fc`. Unfortunately, `fc` reports for every pair of compared files that it didn't find any differences if there are no differences. How can I change that behaviour so that it stays silent when there are no differences and only reports if a file is indeed different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by using the `||` construct which only executes the command on the right side if the exit status of the command on the left side is 0. Since `fc`'s exit status is 0 if it found no differences, the `cat` command won't be run.

```
fc file1.xyz file2.xyz > c:\temp\fc.out || cat c:\temp\fc.out
```

If used in a batch file, a `@` should be prepended so that the entired line is not echoed:

```
@fc %1 %2 > c:\temp\fc.out || cat c:\temp\fc.out
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how we can check the ERRORLEVEL return values for `FC`. Create the following batch file:

`test.cmd:`

```
@echo off

rem create two temporary text files to compare
echo asdf > 1.txt
echo qwer > 2.txt

fc /b 1.txt 1.txt > nul 2>&1
echo Test1, errorlevel: %ERRORLEVEL%  / no differences encountered
fc 1.txt 2.txt > nul 2>&1
echo Test2, errorlevel: %ERRORLEVEL%  / different files
fc /b 1.txt 3.txt > nul 2>&1
echo Test3, errorlevel: %ERRORLEVEL%  / Cannot find at least one of the files
fc /b > nul 2>&1
echo Test4, errorlevel: %ERRORLEVEL% / Invalid syntax

rem cleanup
del 1.txt 2.txt
```

Run `test.cmd`

Result:

```
Test1, errorlevel: 0  / no differences encountered
Test2, errorlevel: 1  / different files
Test3, errorlevel: 2  / Cannot find at least one of the files
Test4, errorlevel: -1 / Invalid syntax
```

Putting it all together:

`compare.cmd:`

```
@echo off
fc /b %1 %2 > nul 2>&1

If "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
  echo different!
  rem <- do whatever you need to do here... ->
)

If "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
  echo No difference!
)

If "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="2" (
  echo File not found
)
 
If "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="-1" (
  echo Invalid syntax
)
```

Comment: This still prints something if there are no differences.